# Unknown project in my GCP projects dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

A new project showed up in my list of projects in my GCP console with name "My Project xxxxx" and ID "brave-watch-nnnnnn" where xxxxx and nnnnnn are numbers. But, I have no privileges on this project and cannot view the resources or modify the project.
I am the only user of my GCP account and my account is not part of any organization. I don't know how this project was created and how it got added to my console. Has anyone encountered such a scenario before and how did you resolve it ?

Comment: I'd contact GCP support.

Comment: Is your IAM identity a member of any Google Groups? Being granted access to a project is not an issue for you - don't panic at this point. The most likely reason is that you share a group that has been granted access to the project.

Comment: You can see in the activity tab (from the console home page) who has created the project

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The activity tab in the console also requires permissions which I don't have and I only see a pretty useless error message _'You don’t have permission to view activities in project "brave-watch-nnnnnn". Ask a project administrator to give you an Owner, Editor, or Viewer role.'_

Comment: @JohnHanley I can't access the IAM tab for the project because I don't have the required permissions in the project. My console user is a part of [Google App Engine](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine) Google group.

Comment: @Matthew Unfortunately, I only have Basic Support and GCP's Basic Support does not provide any useful support apart from redirecting to the GCP documentation and Stackoverflow.

Comment: @vijaypm How have you resolved this? Just noticed the brave-watch-NNNNNN project in my console too.

Comment: @ViktorBrešan No, i haven't been able to resolve this. I just ignore that project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should contact the support team. You mentioned about that your account is not part of an organization. But it's possible for someone to add you into his project via email. Did you leak your email address? You can also use `gcloud projects list` to see which project you have access to.

Comment: Unfortunately, GCP's Basic Support does not provide any support apart from redirecting to Stackoverflow. The project shows up in my `gcloud projects list` even though I have no access. I think your comment of someone accidentally adding me into their project is a possible explanation.

Comment: Report via Help => Send feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

Only the owner of the project can revoke the access... that's who to contact.
b/c permission `resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy` is required to do so.

Comment: The problem is that there is no option to find out the owner of the project because I have 0 privileges on the project.

Comment: When it is listed, you likely have (or had) the permission to view (eg. a typo when inviting a collaborator, as already stated). The most easy might eventually be, to just ignore that entry.